# Google knows the page but doesnt show it

Tags: seo, google-index

There is this link:
http://www.talentblend.com/projects/Female-Dancers-Needed-for-La-Bayadre-The-Royal-Ballet-Flanders/229

You search that in google, it will come up first (no surprise there). This means google has crawled and indexed that page.

But if you search the title of that page 'Female Dancers Needed for La Bayadère, The Royal Ballet Flanders' it will not come up anywhere. But you will see and other page from talentblend.com coming up somewhere on the first page, that is not relevant to the searched words (just vaguely contains that text somewhere on the page).

This has happened when i updated the code on the site. Since then all newly added content behaves like the above example. Old pages still come up high in google (even the ones i deleted since).

Google webmaster tools doesnt say any errors (crawl, security, robots). I also have Google Analytics running on the page.

Can somebody tell me why is this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Search Engine Optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that there is very little actual content on this page. There's the one sentence and then a login form. Was there more content prior to your most recent update?